# Download Sentinel file from S3 using Python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gis, gdal

I am using following code for downloading full size Sentinel file from S3

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.Session().client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='sentinel-s2-l1c',
                        Key='tiles/7/W/FR/2018/3/31/0/B8A.jp2', 
                        RequestPayer='requester')
response_content = response['Body'].read()

with open('./B8A.jp2', 'wb') as file:
     file.write(response_content)
```

But I don't want to download full size image. Is there any way to download image based on latMax, longMin,LatMin and LatMax? I was using below command but it is not working since when data was made requester-payer on S3

```
gdal_translate --config CPL_TMPDIR temp -projwin_srs "EPSG:4326" -projwin 23.55 80.32 23.22 80.44 /vsicurl/http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/tiles/43/R/EQ/2020/7/26/0/B02.jp2 /TestScript/B02.jp2
```

Is there any way to achieve this using Python boto?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rasterio` to access sub-windows of the image:

(I'm assuming that the AWS credentials are set up for use with `boto3` and you have the necessary permissions)

```
import boto3
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.session import AWSSession
from rasterio.windows import Window

# create AWS session object
aws_session = AWSSession(boto3.Session(), requester_pays=True)

with rio.Env(aws_session):
    with rio.open("s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/tiles/7/W/FR/2018/3/31/0/B8A.jp2") as src:
        profile = src.profile
        win = Window(0, 0, 1024, 1024)
        arr = src.read(1, window=win)

imshow(arr)
```

[image: raster plot]

```
print(arr.shape)
```

> (1024, 1024)

Explanation:

If the AWS credentials are properly configured for `boto3`, you can create an `AWSSession` object based on a `boto3.Session()`. This will set the necessary credentials for the S3 access. Add the flag `requester_pays=True` so you can read from the requester-pays bucket.

The `AWSSession` object can be passed into a `rasterio.Env` context, so `rasterio` (and more importantly the underlying `gdal` functions) has access to the credentials.

Using `rasterio.windows.Window` I'm reading the arbitrary sub-window (0, 0, 1024, 1024) into memory, but you could also define a window using coordinates, as explained in the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html).

From there you can process the array or save it to disk.

Comment: sorry but i have read whole documents but still not able to find window() based on latitude and longitude.

Comment: or is there any way to find out col_off row_off based on latitude and longitude

Comment: You'd need to reproject your coordinates into the S2 projection so you can use `rasterio.windows.from_bounds` - there's plenty of docs on point reprojection: e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299787/finding-pixel-location-in-raster-using-coordinates) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168316/pyproj-transform-returning-incorrect-values-epsg-3875-to-epsg-4326) or [that](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/clipping-raster.html).

Comment: in that case i have to download full size jp2 file then i have to reproject it then use latitude and longitude right

Comment: if you don't have your area of interest in projection coordinates, but rather in geographical coordinates, you can try to re-project only these coordinates to create a bounding box in map coordinates. This bounding box can then be used to only access the area you want. Downloading and/or re-projecting the whole image is not necessary